# Joining 3 Tables into one result set

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join

I am trying to join only select columns from 3 different tables and haven't been successful.

Table 1, `Patient`, has the following columns I need:

```
ExternalID, UserDefinedXML, ServiceSiteUid
```

Table 2, `PDI`, has the following columns I need:

```
Patient ID, FirstName, LastName, State
```

Table 3, `ListServiceSite` has the following columns I need:

```
ServiceSiteUid, Name
```

I need to join `Patient` and `PDI` based on the common ID columns `ExternalID` and `PatientID`, and then join `Patient` and `ListServiceSite` by `ServiceSiteUid`.

Here's what I have that has been unsuccessful:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ExternalID, UserDefinedXml, ServiceSiteUid
     FROM 
         Patient) A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         [Patient ID], FirstName, LastName, State
     FROM 
         PatDemogImport) B ON A.ExternalID = B.[Patient ID]
WHERE
    UserDefinedXml IS NOT NULL;
```

I am very new to SQL so please have patience! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why the subselects and what does "unsuccessful" mean in detail? Syntactically it looks OK. Please also consider illustrating your question with the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables involved, sample data for them as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data. Please edit your question to do so, don't post it as comments.

Comment: What's up with all those subqueries?  Why not straight Join it?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]--which includes a clear description of how the desired output is a function of the input. Your current description just more or less echoes your code which you say is wrong--although you don't explain "based" on or what you are doing with nulls. So it's not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
SELECT *
FROM Patient as p
JOIN PatDemogImport as pdi
    ON p.ExternalID = pdi.[Patient ID]
JOIN ListServiceSite as lss
    ON lss.ServiceSiteUid = p.ServiceSiteUid
WHERE p.UserDefinedXml IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM PATIENT  
JOIN 
    PDI on PATIENT.ExternalID = PDI.ExternalID AND PATIENT.PatientID = PDI.PatientID
JOIN 
    ListServiceSite on ListServiceSite.ServiceSiteUid = PATIENT.ServiceSiteUid
where
    UserDefinedXml IS NOT NULL;
```

That should give you what you're looking for. There's no need for subselects in this instance.

Essentially what you are doing is joining the tables based on the relationship between columns. So in the above we join PDI and PATIENT based on their 2 shared columns and ListServiceSite and PATIENT on ServiceSiteUid.

Please note that when you do a SELECT *, you will get duplicate columns in the result (since you're basically getting all the columns across all those tables) so I'd recommend specifying what you select. i.e. `SELECT PATIENT.ExternalID, ....`

Finally, I'd recommend reading up on the different kind of joins. The above is just a regular join but there are several others like `OUTER JOIN INNER JOIN RIGHT JOIN LEFT JOIN` and they all have differences.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Patient.*
FROM Patient INNER JOIN PatDemogImport as pdi ON
Patient.ExternalID=pdi.Patientid
Inner join ListServiceSite on
Patient.ServiceSiteUid=ListServiceSite.ServiceSiteUid
WHERE Patient.UserDefinedXml IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just as simple as this?  You want an inner join and you just need to specify the columns you need.  This should give you exactly the answer you're looking for.  These other answers have the same idea, but they assume that the tables contain only the columns listed and no other columns.  `PatientID` should be the same as `ExternalID` so no need to specify that column and `C.ServiceSiteUid` should be the same as in `Patient`.

```
SELECT A.ExternalID, A.UserDefinedXML, A.ServiceSiteUid, 
       B.FirstName, B.LastName, B.State, 
       C.Name

  FROM Patient A
  INNER JOIN PatDemogImport B ON B.PatientID = A.ExternalID
  INNER JOIN ListServiceSite C ON C.ServiceSiteUid = A.ServiceSiteUid
  WHERE A.UserDefinedXML IS NOT NULL
```